# My Function gets me an No Return found Error

Tags: mysql, function

Hey my MYSQL Funtion get a Error. Her is my Code:

```
SET @UserId = -1;

SELECT Id INTO UserId FROM User 
WHERE UserName = _Username AND Password = _Password;

RETURN UserId;
```

Here is a Screenshot from the Error:

[image]

And this is a Formula

[image]

Comment: Please change to English :) on image

Comment: Also, consider making your title a brief description of your actual error. A title of "Help I'm getting an error" is useless.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon in your select on the image

Answer (score 0):

You got couple problems. First of all reference your variables correctly by using `@` prefix. Secondly, mark function as `DETERMINISTIC` as it should always return the same result for a given user and password combination:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `ValidateUser`(`_Username` varchar(50), `_Password` varchar(50)) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SET @UserId = -1;

    SELECT Id into @UserId FROM User
    WHERE UserName = @_Username and Password = @_Password;


RETURN @UserId;
END
```